# Getting datakind recognised in GADT

Tags: haskell

I'm not certain this is how I want my design to actually look like, but is there any way of getting my GADT to see that the `mt` argument must have kind `MarketType` due its being the type argument to `MarketIndex`?

I think the current type checking is going `mt :: *` so `MarketIndex mt` fails, rather than we need to bulid a `MarketIndex mt` at some point so must restrict `mt :: MarketType`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

module Market.TypesDK where

data MarketType = WinDrawWin
                | AsianHandicap
                deriving (Show)

type family MarketIndex (mt :: MarketType) :: *

type instance MarketIndex WinDrawWin = ()
type instance MarketIndex AsianHandicap = Double

data Market :: MarketType -> * where
  Instance :: mt -> MarketIndex mt -> Market mt
```

The error I get is:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Market.TypesDK   ( TypesDK.hs, interpreted )

TypesDK.hs:32:33:
    The first argument of ‘MarketIndex’ should have kind ‘MarketType’,
      but ‘mt’ has kind ‘*’
    In the type ‘MarketIndex mt’
    In the definition of data constructor ‘Instance’
    In the data declaration for ‘Market’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Maybe I've got the syntax wrong, or maybe I'm asking too much?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your GADT syntax is fine, but only types of kind `*` can have values and since `mt` is used as a field it gets forced to kind `*` by type inference. The workaround to what you are trying to do is to create a a so called singleton type that maps the types of your custom kind to the value level.

```
data SMarketType mt where
    SWinDrawWin :: SMarketType WinDrawWin
    SAsianHandicap :: SMarketType AsianHandicap

data Market :: MarketType -> * where
    Instance :: SMarketType mt -> MarketIndex mt -> Market mt
```

Comment: Ah yes, thank you! I even read through 'Dependently Typed Programming with Singletons' a few months ago when I first looked at all this stuff, but I've clearly not remembered any of it. Time for another read...

Comment: Take a look at the `singletons` package, which will generate for you all such boilerplate singleton types.

Answer (score 0):

@shang has already answered. I just wanted to add that I find it useful to provide explicit type/kind annotations when debugging such problems. For instance, annotating the code with kinds as follows

```
data Market :: MarketType -> * where
  Instance :: forall (mt :: MarketType) .  mt -> MarketIndex mt -> Market mt
```

yields an (arguably) clearer message:

> ```
> Expected a type, but ‘mt’ has kind ‘MarketType’
> In the type ‘mt’
> In the definition of data constructor ‘Instance’
> In the data declaration for ‘Market’
> ```

In your error `mt` is inferred to be a type (`:: *`) which later conflicts with `MarketIndex mt`. By forcing the kind, it is now fine to write `MarketIndex mt`, but now the error states that `mt` should be `:: *` which can ring a bell.

IMHO, I would like the error to be along the line of

> ```
> The type constructor (->) has kind * -> * -> *
> but is applied to an argument of kind ‘MarketType’
> In ‘mt -> ...’
> ```